# NodeJS How to Close Connection To Specific IP?

Tags: node.js

I have one button on my system that have Label "Kill Connection" so if i click on Kill Connection Button that have ip 159.65.87.45 i need to close connection to this ip,a nd other ip needs to be untouched...i start connection using this code:

```
/* STREAM - client */
stream.get('/myapicall/:file/:user/', function(req, res) {                                   
    res.write((fs.readFileSync('/tmp/myfie.m3u8'));
});
```

So i im using rest api and i can't use global variables..so i think it will be better idea to when killconnectionapi is called to close connection to ip address of client...but i don't have idea and how can it be done?

```
/* DROP - connection */
stream.get('/killconnectionapi/:ip/', function(req, res) {                                   
        /* HERE - i need to close connection using ip that i have read from my db */
   res.close('IPofclienttoClose');
    });
```

So if anyone have idea or link for some node plugin or example code so that i can use it to close connection by client ip address?

Thanks

Comment: You are using  single connection in a request.simply put `res.end();` .It should close the current connection

Comment: provide more info! what is stream ?

Comment: then  have to go through it https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_streams.htm to understand what Im saying

Comment: stream is server started at port 8080 and i have first api that is opening connection (/mycallapi) and when i call second api (/killconnectionapi) it needs to kill connection using ip...i can't use res.end() because i im calling connection kill from second api posted above and res.end needs to have ip of client to kill connection right? Using res.end() in second api node does not know to who is connections belongs so it throws error